# How to query a mysql table having key and value pairs

Tags: mysql

**My problem  :**

I have a mysql table which currently stores values from a form which allows organizations to request for a demo from another organization .
The form field values are :
firstname , lastname,email_id,phone.

I am storing these values in key / value pairs in a mysql  table  in the following way :

```
id(int)  form_name(varchar) request_id(varchar) key(varchar)  value(varchar)   
    1        demo                 1479568061        firstname       john
    2        demo                 1479568061        lastname        Deere
    3        demo                 1479568061        email_id   jd@gmail.com       
    4        demo                 1479568061        phone       123-123-1234 
    5        demo                 1479568301        firstname       samuel
    6        demo                 1479568301        lastname        jones
    7        demo                 1479568301        email_id    sj@gmail.com
    8        demo                 1479568301        phone      134-145-1456
```

The  id column is the  primary key .

I have stored (php)timestamp values in request_id  column . Each set of values (per form submission) has a unique timestamp value . For e.g records with id from 1 till 4 will have the same request_id .

**I would like to query my table in such a way so that the administrator can view each set of records pertaining to a single form submission .**
For instance the administrator should be able to view the records in the following way

```
firstname     lastname            email id                tel no 
john          deere               jd@gmail.com            123-123-1234
```

**My research  :**

[MySQL fetching a key value pair which are in two different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769907/mysql-fetching-a-key-value-pair-which-are-in-two-different-columns)

[mySQL query key value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824180/mysql-query-key-value-pairs)

[Need a MySQL query for selecting from a table storing key value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287822/need-a-mysql-query-for-selecting-from-a-table-storing-key-value-pairs)

[Order query results by two key/value pairs, where the fields for the key/value pairs are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992248/order-query-results-by-two-key-value-pairs-where-the-fields-for-the-key-value-p)

Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: That's not a very good way to use a SQL database. It eliminates most of its advantages. [MySQL 5.7 now has the JSON type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) which replaces the need for key/value tables like that. Instead, store and search a single JSON hash. Anyhow, what you're looking for is a SQL pivot, but you should really redesign that table.

Comment: @schwern..thks..have gone through the article on pivot tables at http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78 ....will speak to my project lead on redesigning the table..however group_concat is throwing error ..need your help in creating the query for my problem above using group_concat..